# Is there any performance overhead with sending JSON objects instead of stringified JSON through node js APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, backend, web-development-server

While writing node js APIs, we can send plain JSON objects as params (body params), I think there must be some additional overhead for the formatting instead what if I stringify the JSON while sending to API and will parse back to original JSON while processing it.

Can you guys please suggest if this approach gives any performance advantage?

Comment: If you are using HTTP (which you are) everything ends up being text on each request. So I dont think so, if you "send JSON" it will be converted into text

Comment: What do you mean by _"JSON objects"_? `JSON` is a text format.

Comment: Question doesn't really make any sense if you understand what JSON is

Comment: @charlietfl I think there is a subtle difference between string and Javascript object (JSON). If JSON is same as plain text then whats the purpose of JSON.stringify() [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: A javascript object is ***not*** JSON. JSON is always string. Don't confuse the two. The name JSON derives from them having same structure and syntax but they are not the same things

Answer (score 0):

JSON is "JavaScript Object **Notation**" — i.e. some string format to serialize `Object`, to save, transfer and restore `Object` to/via/from a string. `JSON.stringify()` does not mean you stringify JSON: JSON here is not an object of stringifying, but a namespace like in `Math.sqrt()`. You cannot transfer Object as is via HTTP or IPC: for this purpose, you have a text serialization format, i.e. JSON.